# Prevent tilt in Google satellite layer in ol3-google

Tags: ol3-google-maps

I am very grateful to those at MapGears for the excellent [ol3-google integration](http://mapgears.github.io/ol3-google-maps/) work.

My query is whether it is possible to set the Google Satellite layer to NOT tilt at higher zoom levels? I realise this is the default behaviour, but in OpenLayers 2 it was possible to stop this ([see example](http://geo.nls.uk/maps/dev/explore/index.html)) with code along the lines [googleSat].mapObject.setTilt(0);

I'd be very grateful for any thoughts on help on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Setting the tilt of Google Maps map in OLGM

You can prevent the Google Maps map from tilting by first getting it from the OLGM lib, then set the tilt value that you want:

```
olGM.getGoogleMapsMap().setTilt(0)
```

### Preventing the map from beeing zoomed out/in

This is out of scope of the original question, but still valuable information.

It is currently not possible to prevent the map from being zoomed out to the higher zoom levels.

The problem is this: in order to calculate the zoom level to give to Google Maps, the list of resolutions used has to be the same in the OpenLayers' map.  It is possible to define our own list of resolutions, or simply set `maxResolution` in the OpenLayers' `ol.View`, but doing either of prevents the synchronization between OL and GM.

I'm not saying this is not possible, but it would require development to be able to do so.  I opened an [issue on ol3-google-maps GitHub](https://github.com/mapgears/ol3-google-maps/issues/154) to track this.

Comment: Many thanks for your quick answer, Alexandre. I understand the problem you describe, which prevents a maxResolution from being set. Just to add that my query really related to whether we can prevent the 45 degree tilt in the Google Satellite layer at higher zoom levels, which in OL2 was a simple line of code - [googleSat].mapObject.setTilt(0); - and was not related to Resolution. Would this require development work also in ol3-google maps?

Comment: Oh!  Do you mean this? `olGM.getGoogleMapsMap().setTilt(0)`

Comment: Yes, thanks Alexandre, that's exactly what I was hoping for! I've tested it now and it works perfectly - thanks ever so much.